# Select a single tableView row

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to select a predefined cell on my tableView. On viewDidLoad() I added this code

```
tableView.selectRow(at: selectionIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
```

This dose work only if I set self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection to true. Otherwise the cell is not being selected. Do you have an idea about the problem. I also did `self.tableView.allowsSelection = true` and still have the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your code to viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableView.selectRow(at: selectionIndexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
}
```